# Transposing data table on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple SQL query returning the count of each event in my dataframe. The problem is that the result is a flat datatable with each column representing the count of each event

example:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4
 10       9        15     12
```

I would instead like the data-table to be 2 columns with the label of the event and the count value associated with it

example:

```
col_1      10
col_2       9
col_3      15
col_4      12
```

This is the query I used to get my initial output:

```
select count(col_1) as col_1, count(col_2) as col_2,
count(col_3) as col_3,count(col_4) as col_4 
from table
```

Comment: investigate PIVOT options

Comment: In this case UNPIVOT options

Comment: Are the number of columns(col_1,col_2,col_3) fixed?? Or there could be more

Comment: @Standin.Wolf the numbers are not fixed

Comment: Could you post the sql query which displays the results?

Comment: I got the answer but I am not able to post it here. If you could do some edits to the question,it might open up the box to answer\

Comment: Is this relating to MySQL or Redshift? It can't be both.

Comment: @Standin.Wolf i have posted my initial query

Comment: @Emm I have the answer but I am not able to post it. You either create a new question or try to open up this one. This question is marked as duplicate for some reason